# -Perform doesn't show up when creating a custom segue

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

When with custom segues in Xcode 7.3 the -perform method doesn't show up when trying to type

```
    override func perform() {}
```

the -perform method doesn't appear. Even if I just type it the *sourceViewController* and *destinationViewController* are not available.

I am using a cocoa touch file and the subclass is *UIStoryboardSegue*.

Answer (score 0):

you will want to use the method

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("identifierOfYourSegue", sender: nil)
```

in order to call the segue you make in code and make sure you click the segue in the storyboard and under its attributes have the same exact identifier you used in the call. Then if you want to access the code that runs when it is called, override this function like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

     if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? CustomViewControllersName {
        //something like the line below in order to initialize and pass values between the view controllers
        //vc.variable = self.variable
     }
}
```

example of a custom segue

```
import UIKit

class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        var firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)


        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)
            secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

            }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController,
                    animated: false,
                    completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes but none of the methods show up for UIStoryboardSegue

Comment: Are you inside of a class of type UIViewController or a subclass of a UIViewController?

Comment: These are methods of UIViewController, not UIStoryboardSegue. If want to override them then create a custom UIViewController. If you want to override properties of the segue then make a custom Segue.

Comment: I'm trying create a custom segue and to do they you have to create a new cocoa touch file with a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue then override to change the segue. My Problem is that when I try to override it their are no methods for the UIStoryboardSegue. So without methods I cannot override or anything pertaining to a storyboard or the functionality of the UIStoryboardSegue class.

Comment: I editted my post to include a custom segue example i got from this tutorial [A Beginner’s Guide to Animated Custom Segues in iOS 8](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/)     I don't keep up with past versions of Xcode. Why don't you just update Xcode?